# Loading Javascript file into it's own namespace

Tags: javascript

How do I load a javascript file into it's own object. Lets say I've got a javascript file that's at http://example.com/example.js with the following contents:

```
var x = 5;
var y = 42;
```

In another file, I want to be able to do something like the following:

```
var a = loadJSFile("http://example.com/example.js");
```

So that now:

```
a.x == 5
a.y == 42
```

Is there anyway I can achieve this?

(p.s. if it matters you can assume both files are on the same domain)

Comment: Look into Browserify.

Comment: This is impossible, as JavaScript does not have a native modules system (at least not until ES6).